# Python: Recursively count all file types and sizes in folders and subfolders

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I am attempting to count all files in a directory and any sub directories by type and over all size

The output should be a table that looks something like:

```
Directory A             
Number of subdirectories: 12    

|Type|  Count|  TotalSize/kb    |FirstSeen  |LastSeen  |
|----|-------|------------------|-----------|----------|
|.pdf|  8    |80767             |1/1/2020   |2/20/2020 | 
|.ppt|  9    |2345              |1/5/2020   |2/25/2020 |
|.mov|  2    |234563            |1/10/2020  |3/1/2020  | 
|.jpg|  14   |117639            |1/15/2020  |3/5/2020  |
|.doc|  5    |891               |1/20/2020  |3/10/2020 |
```

Sorry i was trying to get this into a table format for readability. But each record starts with a file type found in the directory.

Comment: so, what have you tried so far and what was the result ?

Comment: I ran a for loop for an os.walk() on a directory. I got all the files names from there and i was going to run a .split() method to parse out the extensions and try to count them that way, but that doesnt give me the rest of the directory information for that file. And i figured there is probably a more elegant way of doing it also.

Comment: >>> os.stat('zappa')
`posix.stat_result(st_mode=33261, st_ino=17836558, st_dev=2065L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=1122896, st_atime=1558260586, st_mtime=1125048678, st_ctime=1475298458)` -- do you need anything beyond that?

Comment: is posix something i need to define?

Comment: i need the actual counts by file extension and the cumulative size for each of those extensions. Unless i am missing something from the stat_result() output there, i seem to be missing it

Comment: from `os.stat()` you have the file size and access times, do you need anything else? you already know how to parse extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want, count the size mapped by extensions. Tidy it up, pretty print the way you like, and you are done.

```
import os

def scan_dir(root_dir):
    # walk the directory
    result = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        # count the files size
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1].upper()
            size = os.stat(path).st_size
            result[ext] = (result[ext] if ext in result else 0) + size
    return result

print(scan_dir("."))
```

Edit: This doesn't collect the min/max timestamps for you, nor counts the files, but this should really put you on the right track.

Comment: you don't have to scan folders manually when using `os.walk()` -- `for dir in dirs` is basically useless

Comment: @lenik, you are right, actually, its worse than useless, it will count the sizes multiple times. Thanks for noticing, removing.